# Instagram graph api media posts between dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to retrieve last month's media posts from an Instagram Business profile I manage, by using `'since'` and `'until'`, but it doesn't seem to work properly as the API returns posts which are out of the time range I selected.

I'm using the following string to call the API:

```
business_profile_id/media?fields=timestamp&since=2018-04-01&until=2018-04-30
```

while the Python snippet would be this (using the same [**init**](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk/blob/master/facebook/__init__.py) script from the facebook-python-sdk)

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)    
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'media?fields=caption,permalink,timestamp&since=2018-04-01&until=2018-04-30')
```

where get.connections is

```
def get_connections(self, id, connection_name, **args):
    """Fetches the connections for given object."""
    return self.request(
        "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(self.version, id, connection_name), args)
```

and request is

```
def request(
        self, path, args=None, post_args=None, files=None, method=None):
    """Fetches the given path in the Graph API.
    We translate args to a valid query string. If post_args is
    given, we send a POST request to the given path with the given
    arguments.
    """
    if args is None:
        args = dict()
    if post_args is not None:
        method = "POST"

    # Add `access_token` to post_args or args if it has not already been
    # included.
    if self.access_token:
        # If post_args exists, we assume that args either does not exists
        # or it does not need `access_token`.
        if post_args and "access_token" not in post_args:
            post_args["access_token"] = self.access_token
        elif "access_token" not in args:
            args["access_token"] = self.access_token

    try:
        response = self.session.request(
            method or "GET",
            FACEBOOK_GRAPH_URL + path,
            timeout=self.timeout,
            params=args,
            data=post_args,
            proxies=self.proxies,
            files=files)
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
        response = json.loads(e.read())
        raise GraphAPIError(response)

    headers = response.headers
    if 'json' in headers['content-type']:
        result = response.json()
    elif 'image/' in headers['content-type']:
        mimetype = headers['content-type']
        result = {"data": response.content,
                  "mime-type": mimetype,
                  "url": response.url}
    elif "access_token" in parse_qs(response.text):
        query_str = parse_qs(response.text)
        if "access_token" in query_str:
            result = {"access_token": query_str["access_token"][0]}
            if "expires" in query_str:
                result["expires"] = query_str["expires"][0]
        else:
            raise GraphAPIError(response.json())
    else:
        raise GraphAPIError('Maintype was not text, image, or querystring')

    if result and isinstance(result, dict) and result.get("error"):
        raise GraphAPIError(result)
    return result
```

Basically I'd like to get posts for a certain period and then get insights for each one.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: I stumbled into the same issue. So far I've tried to use 'since' and 'until' with UNIX timestamp as it looks like they're using that format to filter data on an account level, but no luck. 

Did you find a solution since you posted this?

Comment: Hi Flavien, I posted an update below.

Comment: This post is 1 year old. Is there any known updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the `since` and `until` parameters are not supported on this endpoint and this endpoint has only support cursor based pagination. The only way to do what I wish to do is to load each page of results individually using the `before` and `after` cursors provided in the API response.

Answer (score 0):

For your task, I would recommend you to not use InstagramAPI library. I will show you a simple solution for this using [instabot](https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot) library. For pip installation of this library, use this command:

`pip install instabot`

Use the following python code to get the media within the specified date range.

```
import datetime
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="YOUR USERNAME", password="YOUR PASSWORD")

def get_media_posts(start_date, end_date):
   all_posts = bot.get_your_medias()
   filtered_posts = []

    for post in all_posts:
        post_info = bot.get_media_info(post) #the media info for the post
        post_timestamp = post_info[0].get('taken_at') #get the timestamp of the post
        post_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(post_timestamp).date() #convert timestamp to date

        if post_date >= start_date and post_date <= end_date:
            filtered_posts.append(post) #or you can also use: filtered_posts.append(post_info)

    return filtered_posts
```

This will return you a list of all the posts within the specified date and you can use the `bot.get_media_info(post)` to see what is inside every post.

NOTE: start_date and end_date should be in date() (and not in datetime) format according to this code but you can compare with whatever datetime function you want :)