# How to get all posts in a limited date range in Instagram Graph API?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I need to retrieve all posts from the instagram page associated to my business account.

The Instagram API [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#get-media) does not mention any way to get media only between a certain period.

I´ve tried a analog request with the one I use in Facebook API

```
/{my_business_account_id}/media/?limit=100&period=day&access_token={my_user_access_token}&since=2019-02-23&until=2019-02-24&fields=id,caption,like_count,media_type,media_url,timestamp,permalink,username
```

That request works but ignores the since / until parameters and retrieve literally all my posts.

How do I limit the date range of the retrieved posts?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50946962/5696380:

> Unfortunately the *since* and *until* parameters are not supported on
>   this endpoint and this endpoint has only support cursor based
>   pagination.